# Failed to calculate the value of task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'

Tags: gradle, bamboo, toolchain

I am trying build a service on Bamboo and using gradle build tool but getting below error:

```
error   26-Apr-2022 16:48:02    > Failed to calculate the value of task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
error   26-Apr-2022 16:48:02       > Unable to download toolchain matching these requirements: {languageVersion=17, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}
error   26-Apr-2022 16:48:02          > Could not GET 'https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/binary/latest/17/ga/linux/x64/jdk/hotspot/normal/adoptopenjdk'.
error   26-Apr-2022 16:48:02             > Connection reset
```

Thanks
Anupam

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle.kts Try

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```